# How to keep values after lag?

Tags: r

I'm trying to lag a column, but the values disappear.

**Example Data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3),
                 y = c(3, 5, 1),
                 z = c(2, NA, NA))

df
```

```
x   y    z 
1   3    2      
2   5   NA      
3   1   NA
```

**Current lag function**

```
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  mutate(x = lag(x, 1))
```

```
x   y    z 
NA  3    2      
1   5   NA      
2   1   NA
```

I would like for it to look like this:

**Expected Output**

```
x   y    z 
NA  3    2      
1   5   NA      
2   1   NA  
3  NA   NA
```

Comment: Where do you want the 4 to go exactly? Did you just want to append NA to the start of your list? `c(NA, x)`?

Comment: What is your purpose of using `lag`?

Comment: I want to use `lag` to add NAs at the beginning of a list. If this is a dataframe, I want only the specified column to be affected by `lag`. If I use lag in a dataframe, all the columns are affected by `lag`.

Comment: Add a filter to select only the columns which to `lag`?

Comment: If you attempt to use this not-reducing version of `lag`, you will run into problems when attempting to assign to another column, since length of 5 cannot be assigned to 4 rows. I see that you aren't demonstrating here with a frame, but `dplyr` is focused on frame-centric operations.

Comment: Since you're intending to use this conditionally on columns within a frame, perhaps you can extend your sample data to be a frame, and then add what you expect the post-lag output to be. Thanks!

Comment: That's good to know. I updated my question based on these comments.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr`'s `lag` function cut the vector in the end so to fit the initial length. So `lag`'s input is 3-element vector and output 3-element vector in your example. Your idea is to have input 3-element and ouput 4-element. So you need to act on the structure of dataframe (number of rows) than on the level of individual columns, it is the area where `lag` is working. Please see the code below, please pay attention that I did not checked for negative values, for how many to shift, multiple columns and so on.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3),
                 y = c(3, 5, 1),
                 z = c(2, NA, NA))

lag2 <- function(df, col_name, n) {
  col_res <- c(rep(NA, n), df[, col_name])
  temp <- df[1:n, ]
  temp[] <- NA
  df <- rbind(df, temp)
  df[, col_name] <- col_res
  df
}


df |> lag2("x", 1)
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z
1 NA  3  2
2  1  5 NA
3  2  1 NA
4  3 NA NA
```